# Understanding Haskell Type

Tags: haskell

I have managed to implement a mock filter functions (after lots of attempts)

```
filter' :: (Num a, Eq a) => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' a [] = []
filter' a (x:xs) = if a x
  then x : filter' a xs
  else filter' a xs
```

What I don't clearly understand is the type declaration

```
filter' :: (Num a, Eq a) => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
-- filter' (<10) [1,2,3] 
-- output = []
```

We pass in `(<10) [1,2,3]`. However in the type declaration `(a -> Bool)` we pass in a which comes from the list recursively and the output is either true or false. However what about the expressing the test `(<10)?` Why don't we add another Bool?

Comment: Add another `Bool` where ?

Comment: (<10) is a function and has type (a -> Bool). [1,2,3] is a list and has type [a]. The filter function takes this function and a list and returns another list.

Answer (score 8):

The type of your `filter'` function is only so constrained because you've declared that it is. If you don't declare the type, the compiler will infer a more tolerant type: `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. This is the same type as the built-in `filter` function:

```
Prelude> :type filter
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

The expression `(< 10)` is a so-called *section*. It's a partially applied function.

The operator `<` is itself a function:

```
Prelude> :type (<)
(<) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

You can read this as: `<` is a function that takes two arguments, both of the generic type `a`. The type `a` must belong to the typeclass `Ord`. When you call `<` with such two values, a `Bool` value is returned.

Since Haskell functions are *curried*, you can call a function with only some of the arguments. The return value is a new function that 'waits for the remaining arguments':

```
Prelude> :type (< 10)
(< 10) :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Bool
```

This type is a little more constrained, because the literal `10` is inferred to belong to the `Num` typeclass. Since `<` is in use, the original constraint for that (`Ord`) is still in effect as well.

The expression `[1,2,3]` is is by the compiler inferred as:

```
Prelude> :type [1,2,3]
[1,2,3] :: Num t => [t]
```

The values all belong to the `Num` typeclass. When you use all of these types together, you get the union of all the inferred types:

```
Prelude> :type filter (< 10) [1,2,3]
filter (< 10) [1,2,3] :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a]
```

The `Num` typeclass is inferred because of the use of literals, and the `Ord` typeclass is inferred because of the use of the `<` operator.